# showModalDialog in SpreadsheetApp Won't Close

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried to create a script to run the Spreadsheet APP, by utilizing showModalDialog, Yes - No Button, and ui.Alert.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting showModalDialog to close after I select the Yes Button.

This is my script :

```
  function showDialog() {
    
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService
                     .createHtmlOutput('<p><b>TEXT HTML  HERE</b></p><br><br><br><br><button onclick="google.script.run.clickYes()">YES</button><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">NO</button>');
                    
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'CONFIRMATION');
     } ;

    function clickYes() {
          setSheetMaster(); 
          google.script.host.close();            
          } ;       

    function setSheetMaster() {

      var ui          = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response2    = ui.alert( 'Please Select "NO", to Cancel, and "YES" to Continue' ,
     ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
      );

     if (response2 == ui.Button.YES) {
         Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
        } else {
          return
        }
    };
```

[image: showModalDialog in SpreadsheetApp Won't Close]

As shown in the image, showModalDialog should close, while ui.alert response2 displays. I've used the additional

> google.script.host.close();

but it did'nt work to close  showModalDialog.
Any suggestions for improvement? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @TheMaster ,  For response2, it's actually not a problem, there are advanced functions and it can work. My only problem is that when I select Yes on showModalDialog, the dialog won't closes, and  'var response2' ui  appears to. 
I use ui.alert return , to run another script below.
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed 3 modification patterns. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, `google.script.run.clickYes()` and `google.script.host.close()` are run with an asynchronous process.

```js
function showDialog() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p><b>TEXT HTML  HERE</b></p><br><br><br><br><button onclick="google.script.run.clickYes();google.script.host.close();">YES</button><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">NO</button>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'CONFIRMATION');
}

function clickYes() {
  setSheetMaster();
}

function setSheetMaster() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response2 = ui.alert('Please Select "NO", to Cancel, and "YES" to Continue',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
  );
  if (response2 == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, `google.script.run.clickYes()` and `google.script.host.close()` are run with a synchronous process.

First, `google.script.run.clickYes()` is run. And, the script of `clickYes()` is run. Then, when the dialog opened with `clickYes()` is closed, `google.script.host.close()` is run.

```js
function showDialog() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p><b>TEXT HTML  HERE</b></p><br><br><br><br><button onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).clickYes()">YES</button><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">NO</button>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'CONFIRMATION');
}

function clickYes() {
  setSheetMaster();
}

function setSheetMaster() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response2 = ui.alert('Please Select "NO", to Cancel, and "YES" to Continue',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
  );
  if (response2 == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 3:

In this modification, after `google.script.run.clickYes()` is run, `google.script.host.close()` is run with a new dialog. And, `setSheetMaster()` is run.

```js
function showDialog() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p><b>TEXT HTML  HERE</b></p><br><br><br><br><button onclick="google.script.run.clickYes()">YES</button><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">NO</button>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'CONFIRMATION');
}

function clickYes() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close()</script>').setWidth(10).setHeight(10), 'sample');
  setSheetMaster();
}

function setSheetMaster() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response2 = ui.alert('Please Select "NO", to Cancel, and "YES" to Continue',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
  );
  if (response2 == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: It's work. What I want was your Modified Script 1. But I'm sure, in the future I will need Modified Script  2 and Modified Script  3 too. You gave more than what I asked for. High appreciation for you @Tanaike.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.